# como descargar 2 archivos desde php

Tags: php, php5

estoy intentando lo siguiente pero no me funciona solo me descarga el ultimo archivo si me podrian ayudar se los agradeceria.
he buscado en otros foros y no logro encontrar algo parecido
llegue a leer sobre un frameset pero no lo entendi del todo

````
    $ruc = $_POST['txtRucEmisor'];
    $tipoDoc = $_POST['cboTipoDocumento'];
    $serie = $_POST['txtSerie'];
    $numero = $_POST['txtNumero'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $total = $_POST['txtMontoTotal'];

    $nombre = $ruc . "-" . $tipoDoc . "-" . $serie . "-" . $numero;

    $fileName1 = basename($nombre . ".pdf");
    $filePath1 = 'archivos/'.$fileName1;
    if(!empty($fileName1) && file_exists($filePath1)){
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName1");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");     
        readfile($filePath1);
        exit;
    }else{
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
    $fileName = basename($nombre . ".xml");
    $filePath = 'archivos/'.$fileName;
    if(!empty($fileName) && file_exists($filePath)){
        // 
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");   
        readfile($filePath);
        exit;
    }else{
        echo 'The file does not exist.';
    }
?>```
````

Comment: ¿Con una sola petición quieres devolver dos archivos? Primero se envían encabezados y luego contenido, comenzado el contenido no se vale volver a enviar encabezados.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de javascript para hacer lo que quieres.
En el `href` del elemento a, le pones la url de tu archivo php.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button"),
  link = document.createElement("a"),
  link2 = document.createElement("a");
btn.onclick = () => {
  link.href = "archivo.pdf";
  link.download = true;
  link.click();
  link2.href = "archivo.pdf";
  link2.download = true;
  link2.click();
}
```

```html
<button>Descargar</button>
```